# Parsing an XDocument in .NET and triple point operator

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

In `VB.NET` I used the following to get a tag value:

```
Dim endval = cint(googleXMLdocument...<s:currentItemCount>.Value) - 1
```

How do I do it in `C#`?

I tried the following but it has a syntax error

```
var endval = (short)googleXMLDoc...<s:currentItemCount>.Value) - 1;
```

What is wrong with the `C#` part?

Comment: What is the Syntax error??

Comment: @bash.d `;` expected!

Comment: Well, you got an answer. Try it, maybe it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a legend for that shortcuts on VB.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384974.aspx

There is no C# equivalent, so you have to use standard LINQ to XML methods:

```
.<name>                .Elements("name")
...<name>              .Descendants("name")
.Value                 .First()
.@name                  .Attribute("name")
```

About your example - you should try that in C#:

```
var endval = (short)googleXmlDoc.Descendants("currentItemCount").First() - 1;
```

However, it would be much easier if you show us sample XML and expected outcome.

Comment: now no syntaxerror, but how about i want to loop and use indices?!

Comment: was something like this in vb.net  `Dim seller = googleXMLdocument...<s:name>(counter).Value`